# How can I map the elements to colors in OpenGL VBO?

Tags: java, opengl, jogl, vbo

I'm creating an app using VBO to render some objects with difficult color structure. I noticed, that VBO defines the color of the element equal to last vertex index in the element buffer. For example, when I use point array like this

```
    double pointBuf[]={    -0.1d,  0.1d, 0,
                            0.1d,  0.1d, 0,
                            0.1d, -0.1d, 0};
```

color array:

```
    double colorBuf[] = {   0d, 1d, 0d,
                            0d, 1d, 0d, 
                            1d, 0d, 0d};
```

and element array:

```
   int elementBuf[] = {0, 1, 2};
```

to draw a triangle, it will be red (as the last element in elementBuf is 2, in colorBuf it matches red).

In fact it can lead to additional memory usage to paint everything correctly.

Is there any other possible way to link colors with elements?

Comment: do you really need a double type for your colors? if you are low on memory, use GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE for the color buffer, so R,G,B,A takes 4 bytes total, and not 24 bytes as your implementation does it (if i understood your code correctly). also you dont need doubles for your vertex positions either. just use floats for everything except for colors.

Comment: it's just an example, i don't really need double for colors, i know.
but as i'm operating with great amount of vertexes in small areas i do need such a precision so i have to use double for vertexes.
thanks anyway

Comment: user898722: I edited your question to make it a bit better understandable. Please check that I didn't introduce some mistakes thereby. (Feel free to revert my edit.)

Comment: If you're using doubles for any vertex attribute, you may as well throw away performance. Doubles for attributes are only supported in GL 4.x and even then, with _substantially_ reduced performance. Floats get ~7 digits of precision. Small and large are relative with floating-point values, so unless you actually see a problem, stick with floats.

Comment: Please always specify your OpenGL version when asking OpenGL-related questions.

Comment: Also, what are you referring to as "elements"? In OpenGL terminology, pixels = fragments, and triangles/quads/lines = primitives. A triangle is made of 3 vertices.

Comment: I'm using OpenGL 3.x, thanks for explanations about doubles.
When i said "elements" i thought about "primitives", sorry for my english.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing you need to understand is, that a vertex is not just its position. A vertex (in OpenGL terms) is the whole vector of attributes

```
/ pos_x        \
| pos_y        |
| pos_y        |
| normal_x     |
| normal_y     |
| normal_z     |
| color_r      |
| color_g      |
| color_b      |
| color_a      |
| texcoord0_s  |
| texcoord0_t  |
| texcoord0_r  |
| texcoord0_q  |
| texcoord1_s  |
| texcoord1_t  |
| texcoord1_r  |
| texcoord1_q  |
| …            |
| texcoordN_s  |
| texcoordN_t  |
| texcoordN_r  |
| texcoordN_q  |
| …            |
| attrib0      |
| …            |
\ attribM      /
```

If you change any of these you end up with a completely different vertex. OpenGL's data model has not been designed in a way that it were possible to place each of the attributes in a own array and address them with index vectors. Also this kind of data model would cause major difficulties in implement efficient caching, so would seriously degrade performance.

Also you tell you're running out of memory. Most modern systems offer you several gigabytes of graphics client (i.e. CPU) memory and at least a few hundred megabytes of graphics server (i.e. GPU) memory. The amount of geometry data (i.e. vertices) you can put into GPU memory exceeds the realtime processing capabilities of GPUs; also that would be far more vertices than pixels available on your screen. So I'm positive that you're unlikely to run into any memory problems, your bottleneck will be/is another one.

Answer (score 3):

if you set the Shademodel to smooth, it will interpolate the colors.

glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH);

or what do you exactly want to achieve? only one color for the triangle in the buffer? that doesn't work, you have to specify a color for each vertex...

Comment: The problem is that one vertex can belong to several elements, painted in different colors. So I need to duplicate vertexes?

Comment: yes, duplicate vertices or change the color buffer. maybe there are other possibilities, like using a shader... im not sure about that..

Comment: Thanks for that, i'm looking for "other possibilities", as i'm very limited in memory.

Comment: glShadeModel is GL_SMOOTH by default.